# Add an #hashtag in the URL by using window.location

Tags: javascript

I am having this page `example.com/index.php` with different sections. Each section can be accessed by the following link.

1. first section : `example.com/index.php#first`
2. second section : `example.com/index.php#second`

When the user gets to the page `example.com/index.php`, he is supposed to be directed to the first section so I used this code:

```
<script> window.location = "#first"; </script>
```

Any time I try to access `example.com/index.php#second` I am directed to the first section (`example.com/index.php#first`), instead of being directed to the second section.

Kindly help me solve the issue. Sorry I am not a native english speaker.

Comment: A hashtag is a means of indicating that a term should be hyperlinked to a search engine on social media networks. It gets the name because it it uses a hash character to prefix it. Please don’t confuse other uses (such as fragment identifiers in URLs) of the hash character with hashtags.

Comment: Thanks. what do you think the best way is to fragment a page in my case?

Comment: Does clicking the second (or any) link cause your page to reload? If so the script tag you are inserting into your page will execute again and just send you back to where you started. i.e. #first. What happens if you remove that script tag?

Comment: Clicking on the links does not reload the page. When I try to access `example.com/index.php`, I am directed to `example.com/index.php#first` (which is normal), but When I try accessing `example.com/index.php#second` (and the page reload), I am directed to `example.com/index.php#first`. How can I redirect the user to `example.com/index.php#first` only if there is no hashtag in the URL ?

Comment: uhm... `if(!window.location.hash) {window.location.hash = '#first'}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think in this case it's a matter of using a simple conditional:

```
if(!window.location.hash) {
    window.location.hash = '#first'
}
```

Comment: Would it not be simpler (and tidier) to explicitly set the referring link to example.com/index.php#first ? No need for any JavaScript...